# SNS message is not sent to dead letter queue (DLQ) after retry delivery is exhausted

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a subscription to a SNS topic that is configured to move a message to a DLQ if it can't be delivered successfully to a lambda function.

As described by [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-dead-letter-queues.html), there are client-side and server-side errors. If a client-side error occurred the message is correctly moved to the DLQ but in case a server-side error occurred, the message is not moved to the DLQ. [This document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html) describes the delivery retries and the subscription does use the default delivery policy defined by the SNS topic. The retries do happen but after the retries are exhausted the message is not moved to the DLQ.

Now I wonder why the message is not moved correctly to the DLQ on server-side errors. Is there some more configuration missing?

I created the resources with the following AWS SAM template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  lambda-test

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 30

Resources:
  EmailFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: EmailFunction
      Handler: de.domain.email.App::handleRequest
      Runtime: java11
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      MemorySize: 512
      Environment:
        Variables:
          # https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-aws-lambda-function-performance-for-java/
          JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1
  EmailsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: 'test-emails'
  EmailFunctionInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref EmailFunction
      Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
  EmailDLQ:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Join ['', [!GetAtt EmailsTopic.TopicName, '-dlq']]
  # Policy for DLQ: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-configure-dead-letter-queue.html
  EmailDLQPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      Queues:
      - !Ref EmailDLQ
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: '*'
          Action:
          - 'sqs:GetQueueUrl'
          - 'sqs:GetQueueAttributes'
          - 'sqs:SetQueueAttributes'
          - 'sqs:SendMessage'
          - 'sqs:ReceiveMessage'
          - 'sqs:DeleteMessage'
          - 'sqs:PurgeQueue'
          Resource:
          - !GetAtt EmailDLQ.Arn
  EmailsSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      TopicArn: !Ref EmailsTopic
      Protocol: lambda
      Endpoint: !GetAtt EmailFunction.Arn
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt EmailDLQ.Arn
```

And the  Java function just looks like this (and throws an exception when the message body is `reject`):

```java
package de.domain.email;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SNSEvent;

public class App implements RequestHandler<SNSEvent, Object> {

    public Object handleRequest(final SNSEvent input, final Context context) {
        input.getRecords().forEach(r -> {
            context.getLogger().log(r.getSNS().getMessage() + "\n");
            if (r.getSNS().getMessage().equals("reject"))
                throw new IllegalStateException("reject");
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of server errors are you referring to? Have you waited 23 days for a message to appear?

Comment: @luk2302 the server error is the exception that is thrown. And usually the message should appear in the DLQ once all retries are exhausted, which is the case after a few minutes at most.

Comment: *"For server-side errors caused by AWS managed endpoints backed by Amazon SQS or AWS Lambda, Amazon SNS retries delivery up to 100,015 times, over 23 days."*

Comment: @luk2302 But `numRetries` can only be set to a max value of 100 and it is 3 by default. I wonder if that section is relevant then.

Comment: `numRetries` is for HTTP/S endpoints, which is the only endpoint that supports custom retry policies: *"With the exception of HTTP/S, you can't change Amazon SNS-defined delivery policies. Only HTTP/S supports custom policies. See Creating an HTTP/S delivery policy."* You cannot change the aforementioned retry behaviour for lambda: "up to 100,015 times, over 23 days.".

Comment: If you want custom retry behaviour and better insight into pending messages, etc. I would suggest to send the messages to SQS and have SQS invoke the lambda: SNS -> SQS -> Lambda instead of SNS -> Lambda. On the SQS you can then set proper redrive policies.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks, I tried the SNS -> SQS+DLQ -> Lambda approach now and this one works well. If you want you can add it as an answer since it basically solves my problem and it also seems to be the more flexible approach.